# Cannot find cause for new pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a kubernetes 1.11 cluster that has been running for weeks. Today I noticed this:

```
tooluser$ kubectl get po --sort-by=.status.startTime -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CREATED:.status.startTime,RESTARTS:.status.containerStatuses[0].restartCount
NAME                           CREATED        RESTARTS
pod1-86b8b985f4-78x4c          <10 min ago>   0
pod2-788dbb86df-wj672          <10 min ago>   0
pod3-76d94f5d94-gspqg          <10 min ago>   0
pod4-demo-56cb4bfc68-m2b52     <10 min ago>   0
pod5-69cc97c4c-29dnk           <10 min ago>   0
```

ie looks like the pods have been running for first time (0 restarts), starting 10 min ago, yet these pods have been running for weeks. Further,

- No events in pod.
- I checked the replica sets, no new rs for a week, no rs events;
- same for deployments, and no events in corresponding deployments;
- and same for nodes, no events on nodes;
- no general events (kubectl get events)

Ie I cannot find the reason why these pods that have been running for a week have been started completely fresh. Are there other kubectl commands that I could do to find out?

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented HPA or resource limit, new pods could be scheduled. For resource limit, if memory limit has been breached kubernetes kills the pod and if it has RS creates new one. You can check it with:

```
kubectl get events
```

Or checking logs of kube-scheduler with:

```
kubectl logs $kube-scheduler-pod-name -n kube-system
```

Comment: I checked all sources of events and there are none related to the pod or its Deployment. I didn't know about the kube scheduler logs, but I checked and nothing related to the latest pod started.

Comment: use 'kubectl get pod -n kube-system' to retrieve kube-scheduler pod name then check its logs.

Comment: Yes that is indeed what I did

Comment: Did you try to see the previous pod logs? (kubectl logs my-pod --previous)

Answer (score 0):

The intent was for the following:

1. Kubelet observes a pod is binded to its host.
2. Kubelet records the pod.Status.StartTime
3. Kubelet does a docker pull for container(s) image
4. Kubelet starts the pod

**StartTime** is used mainly with **ActiveDeadlineSeconds** to determine how long a container/pod has been running, and kubelet is responsible for terminating the pod/container once the deadline has been reached. Given that image pulling may take a long time, the active deadline could be inaccurate.

Check logs of specific pods:

```
$ kubectl logs pod_name -n your_namespace -c container_name
```

Then you can check container:

```
$ kubectl exec -it pod_name /bin/bash
```

At the same time check status of [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/).

To get information from logs like reason of starting or failure I suggest you to specify **terminationMessagePath** field of a Container in your pod's definition file. 
Default value is **/dev/termination-log**.

Kubernetes use the contents from the specified file to populate the Container’s status message on both success and failure. Here is documentation [pod-termination-message](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/#customizing-the-termination-message).

More information about pod lifecycle you can find here: [pod-lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/).

Comment: The logs of a specific pod will not contain any info about why/how the pod was started (what node, for what reason, etc).

Comment: I edited my answer and wrote down some clue about using terminationMessagePath field in Pod's definition file.